# Is it possible to change the default screenshot location in Mac OS 9.2.1 (and, if so, how)?

Tags: screen-capture, classic-mac-os

I have an indigo [450 MHz iMac G3 DV+](https://lowendmac.com/2000/450-mhz-imac-dv-summer-2000/) running Mac OS 9.2.1.  I take a *lot* of screenshots, which Mac OS deposits in the root of the iMac's system drive; I've created a subfolder named "Put Screenshots Here" to put the screenshots in instead of having them cluttering up the drive's root directory, but I still have to manually move them there.  Unlike with the Yosemite-running mid-2007 iMac I'm asking this question from (where moving the screenshots to their folder is as simple as selecting them and dragging them over), Mac OS 9 gives screenshots filenames with sequential numerical designations ("Picture 1", "Picture 2", etc.), using the lowest positive integer not already assigned to a screenshot in the system-drive root; thus, moving the screenshots to a subfolder causes Mac OS 9 to start over from Picture 1 with subsequent screenshots, requiring me to manually rename the new screenshots before moving *them*.

Is it possible to change the default save location for screenshots in Mac OS 9.2.1?  If so, how do I do so?

Comment: I've deleted my answer; a better answer may pass on your Q if it's seen as having an answer!